# SPARK: sum of elements with this same indexes from RDD[Array[Int]] in spark-rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have three files like:

```
file1: 1,2,3,4,5
       6,7,8,9,10

file2: 11,12,13,14,15
       16,17,18,19,20

file3: 21,22,23,24,25
       26,27,28,29,30
```

I have to find the sum of rows from each file:

```
1+2+3+4+5 + 11+12+13+14+15 + 21+21+23+24+25
6+7+8+9+10 + 16+17+18+19+20 + 26+27+28+29+30
```

I have written following code in spark-scala to get the Array of sum of all the rows:

```
val filesRDD = sc.wholeTextFiles("path to folder\\numbers\\*")

// creating  RDD[Array[String]]
val linesRDD = filesRDD.map(elem => elem._2.split("\\n"))

// creating  RDD[Array[Array[Int]]]
val rdd1 = linesRDD.map(line => line.map(str => str.split(",").map(_.trim.toInt)))

// creating  RDD[Array[Int]]
val rdd2 = rdd1.map(elem => elem.map(e => e.sum))

rdd2.collect.foreach(elem => println(elem.mkString(",")))
```

the output I am getting is:

```
15,40
65,90
115,140
```

What I want is **to sum 15+65+115 and 40+90+140**

Any help is appreciated!

PS:
**the files can have different no. of lines like some with 3 lines other with 4 and there can be any no. of files.**

**I want to do this using rdds only not dataframes.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to sum up the arrays:

```
val result = rdd2.reduce((x,y) => (x,y).zipped.map(_ + _))

// result: Array[Int] = Array(195, 270)
```

and if the files are of different length (e.g. file 3 has only one line `21,22,23,24,25`)

```
val result = rdd2.reduce((x,y) => x.zipAll(y,0,0).map{case (a, b) => a + b})
```

Comment: Thanks [mck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14165730/mck) perfect answer. I just modified the code a little bit for files with different number of lines.